# Selecting points from an increasing sequence of *finite* $\varepsilon_n$-separated-covering, for any x, can we find an infinite chain converging to x?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

This question is a follow-up of [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588265/selecting-points-from-an-increasing-sequence-of-varepsilon-n-separated-coveri), to which I refer for the relevant notation.

There, the given answer shows via a counterexample that we can't hope to achieve what we want, at least in general.

Here is the question: what if in the previous question we assume that the sets $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ are finite?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true for essentially purely combinatorial reasons.  Let $P$ be the set of finite sequences $(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with $x_i\in X_i$, $d(x_i,x_{i+1})\leq \epsilon_i$, and $d(x_n,x)\leq \epsilon_n$.  These finite sequences form an infinite tree in which every level is finite.  So, by [König's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma), there is an infinite path down the tree, which gives exactly the desired infinite path.

Explicitly, say that an element $x_n\in X_n$ is *good* if for each $N\geq n$ you can extend $x_n$ outward to some sequence $(x_n,x_{n+1},\dots,x_N)$ satisfying the required conditions.  Given a good element $x_n$, there are only finitely many choices of $x_{n+1}\in X_{n+1}$ with $d(x_n,x_{n+1}\leq \epsilon_n$, so one of them must be good.  Starting from a good element $x_0\in X_0$ (which again must exist since $X_0$ is finite), you can then one-by-one pick good elements $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ which combine to form the desired infinite sequence.